How to read a csv (raster) into R and intersect it with a shapefile?
I'm trying to put together a csv dataset(csv_1) and a polygon shapefile (cities_shp) in R. The csv is a raster of 100meters resolution, with a variable of interest named "variable_1" (Shown in the picture below as multiple points). The shapefile has polygons for each multiple cities across the world (shown in the picture below as a single polygon).
I'm trying to create an intersection of the csv file and the polygon shapefile, so I can identify the value of "variable_1" across the city. As you can see in the picture below, the csv points do not correspond geographically to the "cities_shp" locations.
#####################
# Inputs
#####################
## Libraries ##
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)
library(raster)

# Read City polygon
cities_shp = st_read("Input/.../GHS_STAT_UCDB2015MT_GLOBE_R2019A_V1_1.shp") 
cities_shp = st_make_valid(cities_shp)

# Read CSV file
csv_1 = read.csv("Input/.../csv_1.csv") 


#####################
# Graph 
#####################
csv_1_graph = st_as_sf(csv_1, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 3395)
csv_1_graph = st_transform(csv_1_graph, crs = st_crs(cities_shp))
mapview(csv_1_graph) + mapview(cities_shp)


What I did next was the following steps:

to try to rasterize the "csv_1" file and then,
to convert this new raster to a shapefile,
to use the shapefile from step 2, so I can intersect it with the "cities_shp".

I only was able to achieve the 2nd step, because I wasn't able to visualize this new shapefile using the appropriate coordinates. With any of the 2 options I use (below), I don't get how to correct the CRS so I can intersect it with the "cities_shp". Because when I try it, I get an error with any of the options I show below.
Does anyone know how to read this csv file and then intersect it with the shapefile?
Note: I'm showing you just one city in this case, but I have to do it for 10,000 across the world. So, any help is really appreciated!
#####################
# 1st try
#####################
aux_2 <- try(rast(csv_1))
terra::plot(aux_2)
terra::plot(aux_2$variable_1)
aux_3 <- raster(aux_2)
mapview(aux_3,zcol = "variable_1",legend = T)
# Warning message:
#   In rasterCheckAdjustProjection(x, method) :
#   supplied layer has no projection information and is shown without background map
aux_2_polygons = as.polygons(aux_2)   |> st_as_sf()
class(aux_2_polygons)
new_df <- aux_2_polygons %>% st_as_sf(sf_column_name = "geometry", crs = 4326)
mapview(new_df)
#writing: substituting ENGCRS["Undefined Cartesian SRS with unknown unit"] for missing CRS

#####################
# 2nd try
#####################
geoName <- csv_1
geoName_raster <- raster(xmn = min(geoName$x), xmx = max(geoName$x), 
                         ymn = min(geoName$y), ymx = max(geoName$y), 
                         res = 100,crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
geoName_rasterize <- rasterize(geoName[, c('x', 'y')], geoName_raster, 
                               geoName[, 'variable_1'], fun = sum)
plot(geoName_rasterize)
points_matrix <- rasterToPoints(geoName_rasterize)
points_df <- as.data.frame(points_matrix) 
points_sf <- st_as_sf(points_df, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
points_sf = st_transform(points_sf, crs = 4326) #4326
plot(points_sf)
mapview(points_sf)


You assigned the wrong CRS to your csv_1 data. It appears that the correct CRS is WGS84 Pseudo Mercator/EPSG:3857.
However, without knowing of the source of your csv, or how it was created, this may not be correct. You will need to ask the creator of the data to confirm whether it is EPSG:3857 or not.
Either way:
library(sf)
library(mapview)

# Assign EPSG:3857 CRS
csv_1_graph <- st_as_sf(csv_1, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 3857)

# Project to st_crs(cities_shp)
csv_1_graph <- st_transform(csv_1_graph, st_crs(cities_shp))

mapview(csv_1_graph) +
  mapview(cities_shp)



Great, many thanks!! I know is a different question, but do you know by any chance how to recognize automatically the CRS? I mean, how did you know about the right CRS? I need to do this for ~10,000 cities and it will take a lot of time for me to find the appropriate CRS for each one if I do it manually. Many thanks in advance!

@AdrianaCastilloCastillo - 1) I still don't know it's the right CRS :) Not without knowing the source of the data. The best you can do is an educated guess. Best practice is to ask those who created the data. However, in this instance, my first guess was based on the fact that EPSG:3857 is a relatively ubiquitous CRS (Google Maps, OSM et al. use it) and I assumed the data were subsetted from a global DEM so a global CRS seemed a good place to start. Second, I checked the UTM Zone for your data (also relatively common), but your coordinates were outside the bounds for EPSG:32604.


If your csv data values are elevation, sourcing an alternative global DEM with an associated CRS would rule out any guesswork. There are a number of free options such as from the ESA and OpenDEM. I think ESRI may also have data too. DEMs are most often in arc-seconds, so the closest you would likely get to you 100m resolution data would be 3 arc-seconds.



Another way to check is to examine the result of something like st_bbox(filter(cities_shp, UC_NM_MN == "Honolulu")) and st_bbox(csv_1_graph) to see whether they are similar. Again, it does not provide absolute certainty and is arguably impractical (but not impossible) if you have to do this for 13135 cities. You can use epsg.io to check if your coordinates are contained by the projected bounds of your assumed CRS. Again, no certainty, but it can potentially rule out incorrect CRS.



I would be happy to look at answering a new question regarding how to deal with your data. However, it would only be practical to do so if it is not possible to contact those who created the data, or an alternative can’t be sourced (see comment 2 above).



The question would need a) information regarding the sources of all of your csv data e.g. Where was it downloaded/sourced from originally? Does it actually represent a DEM? Do you know a priori that csv_1.csv was for Honolulu?; b) The xmin/ymin, xmax/ymax values for all of your csv data combined e.g. the full extent of all of your data; c) Some more example csv files. Ultimately though, it would still be a guess.


Many many thanks for all your explanations, @l-tyrone!! This is really helpful. I think I'll go ahead with asking the person who provided the data before creating a new question. Again, many thanks!
